# save as .txt format

Tags: java

I made a NotePad program. The problem is it doesn't save in .txt format, It save as a file with no format. But it can open .txt files.  How can i fix it?
Here is my work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class NotePad extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea noteArea;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NotePad p = new NotePad();
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setSize(500,300);
        p.setVisible(true);
    }


    public NotePad() {
        super("Java Notepad");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        noteArea = new JTextArea("",20,20);
        noteArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        noteArea.setLineWrap(true);

        Font font = new Font("sanserif", Font.BOLD,14);
        noteArea.setFont(font);

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(noteArea);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem openMenu = new JMenuItem("Open");
        openMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
                openFile.showOpenDialog(new NotePad());
                loadFile(openFile.getSelectedFile());
            }


        });
        JMenuItem saveMenu = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
                saveFile.showSaveDialog(new NotePad());
                fileSaved(saveFile.getSelectedFile());
            }

        });

        JMenuItem exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Close");
        exitMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });

        fileMenu.add(openMenu);
        fileMenu.add(saveMenu);
        fileMenu.add(exitMenu);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    }

    public void loadFile(File file) {
        noteArea.setText("");
        try {

            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;

            while((line =read.readLine())!=null) {
                noteArea.append(line +"\n");
            }
            read.close();
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
        }
    }


    public void fileSaved(File file) {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
            String[] lines  = noteArea.getText().split("\\n");
            for (String ) {

                writer.println(words);

            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

btw I can't post my question because of not explaning the scenario according to the site. So there. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure that the output is NOT in text format?!? .txt is not a format but an extension...

Comment: If you are running on Windows, turn off "hide known file extensions" in the view options of your windows explorer.

Comment: `"btw I can't post my question because of not explaning the scenario according to the site"` ???? what ????

Comment: I don't know Java, but I'm guessing that you need to specify a list of possible file extensions to save with.

Comment: I want it to be like windows notepad. Where you have an option to save it as .txt type

Comment: @minitech That is gold +1 to you

Comment: @user118: check out the JFileChooser API and tutorial as this will explain exactly how to do what you're trying to do. Copy these important links as you will use them a lot: [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you adding the ".txt" extension to the end of the output file name if it does not exist.  Java and Windows aren't going to do it for you...

```
public void fileSaved(File file) {
    String name = file.getPath();
    if (!name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
        name += ".txt";
        file = new File(name);
    }

    //...
```

This is pretty heavy handed as I've not checked to see if the user has provided a different extension, but I think NotePad basically does the same thing :P

Answer (score 0):

Every file name consists of two parts : - NAME and EXTENSION.
Notepad , by default saves as .txt but that is not always the case.

You need to give the extension as

```
public void fileSaved(File file) {
String name = file.getPath();
if (!name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
    name += ".txt";
    file = new File(name);
}
```

in order to make it work. Try it out.